# How do I open or convert a Microsoft Works .XLR spreadsheet to an Excel compatible format?

Tags: conversion, spreadsheet, microsoft-works

I have been sent a Microsoft Works XLR spreadsheet and Excel will not open it.

- Is there any way of opening an XLR file directly in Excel?
- Can anyone recommend a (free) tool for converting to an Excel compatible format, ideally XLS?
- Can any other spreadsheet apps (e.g., OpenOffice, Google Spreadsheets) open XLR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the file's extension from xlr to xls.
This method used to work fine in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Changing .xlr to .xls extension didn't work for me – it complained about file corruption.

You're maybe trying to open it by double clicking it. Don't bother with conversion software just run Microsoft Excel and then select *File > Open*.

Then browse for the .xlr file (you may need to set file types to 'All' to view the .xlr for selection) and click *Open*.

The .xlr file will then open in Microsoft Excel. Then simply select *File > Save As…* using the desired file type (e.g. .xls, .xlsx).

I've just tried this myself and it works fine (office 2010).

Comment: For Office 2010 Starter users, note that because of its virtualization abomination, it is non-trivial to create the appropriate filetype association, because no excel.exe exists on disk to select as the handling program.  You can "copy" the .xls handler entry in the registry (see http://mypersonalnerd.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-open-microsoft-works-xlr-wps.html), which has worked for some people (but didn't work for me).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the standalone Excel viewer will open xlr files that Excel cannot, if viewing the spreadsheet is helpful to you.

Otherwise, the only option that I am aware of is to open the file in Works and Export it as an old type of Excel file that Excel will open.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163109) is a rather dated page on Microsoft's site giving the formats to use.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried many times to open an xls file with no success up to now. I have got Open office in my computer, I opened up open office went to file, then to open a document, found my file in my documents clicked on it into file name, then open and at last it opened.

Comment: XLR files are not the same as XLS files. Microsoft Works is in a corner by itself, unfortunately.